# Find a column by email in asp.net Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, entity-framework-6.1

I want to write forget password as a training and now I have a problem with it.

I need to find a userId but my code is not working currectly and it show me SQL code.

This is my code:

```
private string NewPass()
{
    UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager =
        new UserManager<IdentityUser>(new UserStore<IdentityUser>());

    string userId = (from x in db.AspNetUsers
                     where x.Email == txtEmail.Text
                     select x.Id).ToString();
    return userId;
}
```

I have an email address and now I want to find the userId by the email address

But as I said my code just shows me the SQL statement, not the value of column I want

What's wrong with my code?

With respect

Comment: Replace .ToString() with .FirstOrDefault()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the issue is : this statement *could* return multiple rows:

```
from x in db.AspNetUsers
where x.Email == txtEmail.Text
select x.Id
```

so you cannot just convert this to a string.

What you need to do is:

- select the first (or possibly only) row from the result set
- make sure it's not NULL
- then return the `Id`

Try this:

```
 var users = (from x in db.AspNetUsers
              where x.Email == txtEmail.Text
              select x).FirstOrDefault();

 string userId = string.Empty;

 if (users != null) 
 { 
    userId = users.Id;
 }

 return userId;
```

Comment: thanks a lot for helping me,  you answer is the only current answer for me,  and you explained it very very good,  thank you again,    with respect

Answer (score 0):

You are returning .ToString() which shows the SQL behind the LINQ query.

Fetch the user object, then access it's ID, something like this (not tested at all):

```
private string NewPass()
{
    UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager =
        new UserManager<IdentityUser>(new UserStore<IdentityUser>());

    /// Fetch the user object
    IdentityUser user = (from x in db.AspNetUsers
                     where x.Email == txtEmail.Text
                     select x).SingleOrDefault();
    return user != null ? user.Id : String.Empty;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are returning .ToString() which shows the SQL behind the LINQ query.

```
private string NewPass()
{
UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager =
    new UserManager<IdentityUser>(new UserStore<IdentityUser>());

IdentityUser user = (from x in db.AspNetUsers
                 where x.Email == txtEmail.Text
                 select x).FirstOrDefault();
if(user !=null)
return user.Id;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
var x = from data in _db.AspNetUsers.AsQueryable() 
where data.Email == txtEmail.Text select data.Id;

        if (x.Any())
        {
            // do your opertion
        }
```